# Knowing the state of orange button in motorola MC65

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, motorola, motorola-emdk

I need to be able to know what is the current state of orange button and be notified if this state has changed on Motorola device MC65.
Sadly I can't use Symbol.Keyboard.KeyPad class since it is not supported on MC65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docos state:

> Keyboard Supported feature - Only the following two API’s are
>   supported on MC65.
>
> Symbol.Keyboard.KeyPad.SetKeyState. 
>   Symbol.Keyboard.KeyPad.GetKeyStateEx.
>
> Following keys are not supported in MC65. KEYSTATE_ALT, KEYSTATE_CTRL,
>   KEYSTATE_NUMLOCK, KEYSTATE_NUMERIC_LOCK, KEYSTATE_CAPSLOCK
>
> For the MC65, Microsoft APIs cannot be used to get the Orange key
>   states. **The Symbol.Keyboard.KeyPad class provides a new
>   GetKeyStateEx() function to get the current state of the modifier
>   keys**. Refer to the API function’s page for a description of this API.

And it has this code sample:

```
// Get the key states
int keyState = keypad.GetKeyStateEx();

bool lockedState = false;

// Checking for a lock state first as it cannot be combined with others
switch (keyState)
{
    case KeyStates.KEYSTATE_ORANGE_SHIFT_LOCK:
        checkBoxOrangeShiftLock.Checked = true;
        lockedState = true;
        break;
    case KeyStates.KEYSTATE_FUNCTION_LOCK:
        checkBoxFuncLock.Checked = true;
        lockedState = true;
        break;
    case KeyStates.KEYSTATE_ORANGE_LOCK:
        checkBoxOrangeLock.Checked = true;
        lockedState = true;
        break;
    case KeyStates.KEYSTATE_NUMERIC_LOCK:
        checkBoxNumLock.Checked = true;
        lockedState = true;
        break;
    case KeyStates.KEYSTATE_SHIFT_LOCK:
        checkBoxShiftLock.Checked = true;
        lockedState = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

if (lockedState)
{
    // No need to continue if a locked state
    this.Update();
    return;
}

// Process unlock or temp lock states if any
this.checkBoxUnShift.Checked = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_UNSHIFT) != 0;
this.checkBoxShift.Checked = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_SHIFT) != 0;
this.checkBoxCtrl.Checked  = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_CTRL) != 0;
this.checkBoxAlt.Checked    = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_ALT) != 0;
this.checkBoxNum.Checked = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_NUMLOCK) != 0;
this.checkBoxCaps.Checked = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_CAPSLOCK) != 0;
this.checkBoxFunc.Checked = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_FUNC) != 0;
this.checkBoxOrangeTemp.Checked = (keyState & KeyStates.KEYSTATE_ORANGE_TEMP) != 0;
```

Hope that helps!