# How to handle Blue/Orange button on Motorola MC55 or MC65 (Hardware button)

Tags: keyboard, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6.1

i am working with Motorola MC55/MC65, and i found using `Symbol.Keyboard.KeyPad` but when i create an instance from "KeyPad" it's crashing with exception "KeyState notification is not supported".

Stack Trace like below;

```
   at v.h(IntPtr A_0, UInt32 A_1)
   at Symbol.Keyboard.KeyPad..ctor()
   at TestProj.Form1.btnOK_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at TestProj.Program.Main()
```

I'm confused, how can i catch orange button or blue button pressed?

Comment: Possibly you have to add a runtime for this API usage to the device.

Comment: i tried, getting same error..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13859711/945456